# Visual Studio Community cannot build one of my files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-community

There's a `.cpp` file in my project. I can see Unresolved external symbol errors related to this file.

I tried to compile the file individually using the context menu in Solution explorer. This was the result:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ProjectName, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Cannot build selected files.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I click properties in the solution explorer context menu for this file, Visual Studio crashes:

[image]

I tried to remove the file from the project in order to re-add it, this happened:

[image]

I checked and the file is not locked by another program. What is the problem?

Comment: Visual Studio is the problem

Comment: Try to remove the .vs directory, and all database files from your solution directory. Then reload the solution

Comment: Maybe your project file got corrupted. Try creating a new project.

Comment: Reboot, edit the .vcxproj file to not include the file causing the issue, then try to reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this is that the files are in the .filters file, but not in the .vcxproj file. Removing them from the filters file manually and re-adding them should fix the issue.